# What could be the reason for `invalid parent reference 'style/ActionBarTheme'` when generating Android apk?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am building a project from Android Studio using Android SDK 7.0 (26). I'm using gradle file. The project is first synced successfully but when I click  `Build->Generate Signed Bundle/APK`

I get this error:

> org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed
>   Output: /build/intermediates/incremental/mergeReleaseResources/merged.dir/values-v21/values-v21.xml:6: error: invalid parent reference 'style/ActionBarTheme'.`

As far as I understand `ActionBarTheme` is a part of standard Android look and feel. So I'm wondering how it can be not resolved?

Comment: is `ActionBarTheme` inbuilt or Custom

Comment: it is inbuilt theme

Comment: can you show `values-v21.xml`

Comment: I can't unfortunately but in `values-v21.xml` there's a button whose parent is `style/ActionBarTheme` while the parent of `style/ActionBarTheme` is `@android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar`

Comment: Please check the solution.

Comment: The actual problem was gradle version. When I downgraded to version 3.2 everything worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

The only problem is the name of the file `values-v21.xml`. There exists no such file for applying a theme to a button with such name. Hence, rename your file: `values-v21.xml` to `styles.xml` inside your `values-v21` folder.

Rest everything looks fine.

Try it and see if it works.